# What is missing when a Set is null instead of a Hibernate proxy when doing integration testing with Springframework?

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit4

I'm new to hibernate, and trying to start off right with testing out of the gate.  I've been spoiled by Grails' ease of use in this area...  I'm using Springframework 3.0.6 with Hibernate 3.6.8 and Junit 4.9.

I'm trying to understand why the following test does not "see" the EventAttribute Set in the Event object as a set of HibernateProxy Objects, but instead as simply null.  Also, if I follow some of the Event's compound properties (properties made of objects in other tables), I do not see values either, but instead nulls.

The object saves just fine in the dao, and I can see simple properties (properties in the same table).  However the assertNotNull fails in the test below.

My guess is that something is off with my testing configuration, such that the Session is already closed.  Thoughts?

The Models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

  /**
      ... some other properties ...
  */

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
  private Set<EventAttribute> eventAttributes = new HashSet<EventAttribute>(0);

  /**
      ... getters and setters ...
  */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "event_attribute")
public class EventAttribute {

  /**
      ... some other properties ...
  */
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_event_attribute_event")
  @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
  private Event event;

  /**
      ... getters and setters ...
  */
}
```

My Test Configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("dao-testConfig.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional
public class EventAttributeDaoTest  {

  @Test
  public void save(){
    EventAttribute eventAttribute = new EventAttribute("a key", "a value", event);
    dao.save(eventAttribute);

    Event event2 = eventDao.getEventById(event.getId());
    assertNotNull(event2.getEventAttributes());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that hibernate will NOT maintain both ends of an bidirctional reletionship for you.

So as long as you do not realy reload the event from the database, the set will not been updated. In your case the problem is, that `event2` will not be loaded again from the database, because it is already presend in the current hibernate session.

You can prove that by `assertSame(event2, event) //notice that SAME not only EQUALS`

So if you flush and clear the session before you load the second event, then hibernate will really load it from the db and create a new object instance. In this case it will also initalize the `set` in the way you expect.

**But: I my humble opinion, this is poor code. Better is to maintain both sides of the relationship by hand.** So if you create an new EventAttribute, it should itselfe register to the Event, the same for changing. So that in the end the releatinship is correct maintained, even if the Object is not stored in the database.

Comment: This is good to know.  I did not realize that hibernate would return the exact same object to me.  However, my problem is slightly larger than the set simply not being returned.  In the test I am unable to look at anything further in the object graph than the simple types as a part of the event object.  For example, I can see a date and an id for the event, but I cannot see any of the details of a participant.

Comment: @Daniel: sounds strange "but I cannot see any of the details of a participant." could you please post some more details so the code. (Persistence.xml, Test, ...)